# php multi file upload without html form

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm developing a system that contains a folder with XML file and image files. I want user to be able to upload all of the images and XML file.. This is more like a backup for the user.. But I don't want the user to choose hundreds of files one by one..

I've tried many php codes but they are all based on one file upload. How can I upload all of the files in the folder without asking anything from user (no input or button).. and I'm not using any HTML file.

**I tried to "scandir" with php and use it for uploading file but couldnt make it work. It should be something with "scandir" or maybe some Java integration**

Comment: So basically you're doing a _PHP script_ that should, just by itself, send files to some other place, over HTTP - _without_ involving a browser?

Comment: this php file on localhost ( in user's machine). So it is able to dir the folders and return them as an array. but I want to upload these files to the server when user hit "sync" button on the program. It is not html based system..

Comment: Have you considered using something like rsync or does it have to be a custom script?

Comment: no, I didnt try it.. I'm searching for it now.. And its better if i can learn the way and make my own script but if there is a script that works properly i could take it :)

Answer (score 0):

You do realize that `scandir()` would only scan directories on your server, right? PHP executes on the server, not in the client browser.

There is nothing you can do in HTML that would let you get access to a user's directory structure, without exploiting browser security flaws.

As well, using a `<input type="file" ...>` tag is the only method to allow file uploads. Even then, you have minimal control over the tag. They're nearly impossible to style, they allow only minimal information to be available via javascript, etc... HTML5 does allow multi-file uploads in a single tag, but until HTML5 browsers become more commonplace, you're stuck with the old-schoole one-file-per-input method.

Comment: I think I wasnt clear. I also have a wamp server on local side. And I use "scandir" in that localhost (user's host). the folders are inside that localhost. And what I want to do is, allow the user to upload all of the files without repeating "file browsing"..

Comment: HTTP is not suitable for doing large file uploads, or doing 'many' small files. If you've got wamp server running on the local machine, consider using something like scp/sftp to do the transfers instead. PHP's file upload handling capabilities, frankly, are a load of crap.

Comment: well images are lower than 20kb.. and limited at 100 images.. so makes around 2000kb.. as I searched they say php allows upload up to 8mb.. and if possible i can use a loop to upload those images. But somehow I should be able to "dir" the folder and upload them without bothering the user.. Im not sure but I also heard some methods about using "zip".. I'm open for all solutions.. It could be Php, Java, etc..

Answer (score 0):

As others have stated, HTTP is not the ideal file transfer mechanism.  Why can't you use ftp or ssh2?  PHP has libraries for both of these.  PHP also has a zip library, so you could zip all of the files and send it as one over http as well if they are small enough.

Comment: is there an example for using ftp for this system. What I want to do is, to sync important images and its XML file to online server. So whenever the user (with localhost on his/her machine) made new interface, i wanted to use my sync button to upload those files to online web server. So user will only click "sync" button in the program. And system will upload those files to server automatically..